# How to determine what an existing table's column delimiter is in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, impala

I am working with an existing table in MySQL but I need to know how it was set up.  I need to find the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` setting so I can set up my Impala database accordingly.

Comment: use : SHOW CREATE TABLE mytablename;

Comment: cool, thanks.  If you post as an answer, I'll accept it.  By the way, what it the default separator for MySQL?

Comment: Post the result that you want an i post the Query for it.

Comment: I am just curious if the default separator for MySQL is the TAB, `'\r'`, pipe, `','` or whatever.

Comment: The normal separator is comma ',' but you can change it for every statement or command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use :

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytablename;
```

Or look in the information_schema in the Table TABLES are all informations if you want you build a complex Query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='your_schema' 
  AND TABLE_NAME='your Table' 
  AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE;
```